# Google Apps Script - MailApp

Tags: email, google-apps-script, attachment

I want to send an email with replyTo and attachments using Google Apps Script, but I only found those two methods, that do what I want separately.

```
sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)

sendEmail(to, replyTo, subject, body)
```

There's another method which I can do both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use the first method of

```
sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)
```

This method can take all of your parameters. You pass all of your parameters in the options part.

It will look something like this.

```
// Send an email with two attachments:
//   a file from Google Drive (as a PDF) and an HTML file.
var file = DriveApp.getFileById('12345mnopqrstuvwxyz');
var blob = Utilities.newBlob('HTML content here',
                             'text/html',
                             'my_email.html');

MailApp.sendEmail('mike@example.com',
                  'Attachment example',
                  'Two files are attached.',
                  {
                    attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF), blob],
                    replyTo: 'ReplyTo@Email.com'
                  });
```

### here is a screenshot of the documentation

[image: Google Documentation Image]

[Google documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object))